# Tensorflow Conv2d function - Type error

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a neural net problem, and in the conv2d function, i'm getting a Type mismatch issue.

Here's the code snippet
`conv_layer1 = tf.nn.conv2d(inputs, w_layer1, strides=strides, padding='VALID') + b_layer1`

I'm getting this error

`TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <bound method Kernel.raw_input of <ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel object at 0x000001C0A75CB470>>`

I tried having [1,1,1,1] inline aswell as a variable, but no luck

The complete error trace is here(search for "In [46]:"
https://github.com/mymachinelearnings/CarND-Traffic-Sign-Classifier-Project/blob/attempt1/Traffic_Sign_Classifier.ipynb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a typo. In your notebook, you're feeding `input` into your network which is a built-in python method to get input from e.g. a keyboard. Obviously this doesn't make much sense as input to a convolutional network. Chances are you meant to type `inputs` as in your question?

Note that the syntax highlighting in the notebook shows this quite clearly -- `input` is displayed in green (at least in my browser) signifying that it has a special meaning.

Comment: You know what - you are spot on! How did i make such a simple mistake - lol